# How many where conditions should be there while joining N number of tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

Is there any minimum number of `where` clauses (or any other condition for that matter) while joining N tables in SQL?

Comment: If you use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax, then this question is irrelevant.

Comment: As many as neccessary to join all tables based on their PK-FK-relations.

Answer (score 0):

Joining `N` tables requires `N-1` conditions, assuming none of these is a cross-join.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no compulsion that **WHERE** clause has to be used and there is no limit as well. Joins only require a mandatory **ON** clause.

Having said that, rather than asking a theoretical one liner you should come up with a practical problem so that you can avoid the negative votes.